# Bateman-Horn conjecture, continued

Tags: nt.number-theory

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214704/unexpectedly-prime-rich-cubic-polynomial/214726#214726), we needed to compute the Hardy-Littlewood constant for the Bateman-Horn conjecture. Is there a simple argument to show that the infinite product actually converges? Also, is there a reasonable (for your favorite value of "reasonable") estimate of the convergence speed?

Comment: I really wish that the answer to the first question turns out to be a "no". I would love to see a proof! (Seriously, one probably cannot avoid Chebotarev's density theorem, for if the average of $n_p$ is not $1$, the product would diverge.)

Comment: Wiki articles claims that this product is always positive (without reference), I guess it is also always finite. This is a statement of Chebotarev Density Theorem type, though quite strong.

Comment: @BorisBukh The average of $n_p$ is $1$ when the Galois group is the whole $S_d,$ but it's far from clear for other Galois groups (at least to me). That's part of the reason why I asked the question: from the Chebotarev argument, it is far from clear that the product is always finite.

Comment: @FedorPetrov See my answer, though I don't claim to understand what is going on.

Comment: Two things bug me. First, one can make the constant arbitrary large rational:  take $f(x)=primorial(k)x+1$ (infinitely many terms vanish). Second, there is [Chebyshev bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias) which states "there are more primes of the form $4k + 3$ than of the form $4k + 1$, up to the same limit". So large enough Chebyshev bias might be a hint...

Comment: @joro Chebyshev bias is not strictly speaking true (the sign of the difference does change).

Comment: @IgorRivin Why care about sign change? From wikipedia:  "They, however, do have a logarithmic density, which is approximately 0.9959". This might not be enough for answer of course.

Comment: @BorisBukh: That $n_p = 1$ on average is nothing but Landau's prime ideal theorem for non-normal fields, which is very much simpler than Chebotarev. And here, for the convergence at hand, this is only needed in logarithmic form (Dirichlet rather than natural density), which by a straightforward arrangement amounts to establishing that the Dedekind zeta function has a simple pole at $s = 1$ (and can even be arranged in simple terms not mentioning the zeta function).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the good news is that one can find an argument in the [original paper of Bateman and Horn](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/BatemanHorn.pdf), which also gives the convergence rate, and which does not use Chebotarev. The bad news is that I don't understand why this works if the Galois group of $f$ is such that the average number of fixed points is not equal to $1.$

Comment: The Galois group acts transitively on the roots, and Burnside's lemma gives that the average number of fixed points is the size of the orbit which is one.

Comment: @Lucia I wasn't thinking :( Thanks!