# Polynomials dense with primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p(n)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients.
Define $\Delta( p(n) )$, the *prime density* of $p(n)$, to be
the limit of the ratio with respect to $n$
of the number of primes $p(k)$ generated when the polynomial
is evaluated at the natural numbers $k=1,2,\ldots,n$:
$$
\Delta( p(n) ) \;=\; \lim_{n \to \infty} 
\frac{ \textrm{number of } p(k), k \le n, \textrm{that are prime}}
{n}
$$
For example, Euler's polynomial $p(n)=n^2+n+41$
starts out with ratio $1$, but then diminishes
beyond $n=39$:

---

[image: D100]

---

And it continues to diminish ...

---

[image: D1000000]

---

... and by $n=10^7$ has reached $\Delta=0.22$.

> **Q**. What is the largest known $\Delta( p(n) )$ over all polynomials
>   $p(n)$?

In particular, are there any polynomials known to have $\Delta > 0$?

Maybe these questions can be answered assuming one or more conjectures?

Comment: For degree $1$ and co-prime coefficients $\Delta>0$ (Dirichlet's theorem, Chebotarev density theorem). For degree >1 (and any irreducible $p$), it is an open problem .

Comment: @MarkSapir That would be true if he were multiplying the density by $\log n$, but he isn't, so in fact every polynomial has density zero.

Comment: @WillSawin: Yes, of course. But I thought that log was just missing. Clearly one needs to divide by the number of primes $\le n$ and not by $n$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bateman-Horn conjecture, continued](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214873/bateman-horn-conjecture-continued)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is known (it follows from Brun's sieve, or more modern sieves) that for any fixed polynomial $p$, there exists a constant $c_p$ such that
$$
\# \{ n\le x\colon p(n) \text{ is prime} \} < c_p \frac x{\log x}.
$$
In particular, your density $\Delta$ equals $0$ for any polynomial (as Will Sawin commented).

For irreducible polynomials without obvious obstructions (such as all the values being even), it is conjectured that $\# \{ n\le x\colon p(n) \text{ is prime} \} \sim s_p \frac x{\log x}$ for some constant $s_p$ as $x\to\infty$; but [this is an open problem for any polynomial $p$ of degree greater than $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture).

Answer (score 7):

This has been asked multiple times before (with three variations by yours truly), so is a mega-duplicate, if you will:

[Bateman-Horn, continued even further](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215788/bateman-horn-continued-even-further)

[Bateman-Horn conjecture, continued](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214873/bateman-horn-conjecture-continued)

[Unexpectedly prime rich cubic polynomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214704/unexpectedly-prime-rich-cubic-polynomial/214726#214726)

And even resulted in a preprint:

### Some experiments on Bateman-Horn

### I Rivin - arXiv preprint arXiv:1508.07821, 2015 - arxiv.org